# Convert TTA file to MP3 or WAV file?

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg

I have some `.tta` files I downloaded from internet. I can play them on VLC locally, but they cannot be played from certain media player app, for example, an android app. So here I need to convert "tta" files to "mp3" or "wav" files. Since they're high resolution sound, I'd like to know how to convert them to wav (or flac) rather than to mp3, but if you know I'd like to know both of the ways. So, is there any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in *.tta; do
    ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.tta}.wav"
done
```

Comment: That output argument might be better served as `"${i%.tta}.wav"`

Comment: @roaima thanks, that would be better for me.

Comment: Here I wrote a script for recursive conversion, hope this would helps someone. `tmpIFS=$IFS ; IFS=$'\n' ; for i in $( command find "." -type f | ag tta ) ; 
do
 ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.tta}.wav"
done ; IFS=$tmpIFS`